# Firebase & Angular: *ngFor without Reloading Images

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ngfor

I am using Ionic, Angular and Firebase to build a custom shopping cart for an app where the client has asked for images to feature prominently in the shopping cart. In this view the user can update the quantity of each item in their cart, the problem is that when ever the user updates the quantity of items and the update is sent to firebase - the result comes back and forces the images to reload causing a brief flash where the graphic disappears. The TrackBy feature doesn't solve this but at least limits the effect to an individual item.

The benefits of solving this are twofold: primarily it stops the image flash problem I mentioned, secondly it prevents us having to reload (and pay for) an image from Firebase Storage again.

Thanks in advance :)

**The Firestore Cart Document**

```
cart: [
    {'item_id': 0, 'prod_id': 'ABCDEF', 'quantity': 10, 'image_ref': 'prod_abcdef.jpg'},
    {'item_id': 1, 'prod_id': 'GHIJKL', 'quantity': 50, 'image_ref': 'prod_abcdef.jpg'}
]
```

**The HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let prod of this.cart | async; let cartIdx = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <img [src]="prod['image_url']" />
  <ion-input type="number" [value]="prod['quantity']" (ionChange)="updateQuantity($event, cartIdx)">{{ prod['quantity'] }}</ion-input>              
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.cart = this.loadCart();
}

loadCart(){
  return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user}/cart`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(async (doc) => {
      let user_cart = doc.payload.data();
      user_cart['image_url'] = await this.fireStorage.ref(`product-images/${user_cart['image_ref']}`).getDownloadURL().toPromise();
      return user_cart
    })
  );
}

async updateQuantity(ev, product_idx){
  let new_val = ev.target.value;
  let new_cart = await this.loadCart().toPromise();
  new_cart[product_idx]['quantity'] = new_val;

  this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user}/cart`).set({new_cart});
}

trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really mentioned what exactly you are trying to achieve, and why it's not working at the moment.

But one thing on your trackBy. It.. Works.. But probably isn't ideal. TrackBy in Angular should be implemented so that it returns a unique id per row in the loop. You've implemented it in a way that returns the item index, which is unique, but isn't actually ideal because items may be shuffled but not necessarily changed.

Instead, change your trackby to be :

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.item_id;
}
```

That is assuming that item_id is always unique with the items in the cart. That should probably go a long way to resolving your issues with using Trackby specifically.

More info here : https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/12/04/using-trackby-with-ngfor-loops-in-angular/

Comment: Thank you @MindingData, I will investigate trackBy further and update the question. I’ll also make sure to share any learnings and solutions back to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think also your problem is that every time the qty is updated, the async pipe gets rerun and your call to the storage to get the download url delays the image from showing until that url is recieved.

I think a better approach would be to save the url of the image straight to the product document when you upload the image to storage, and that way you don't have to ask and wait for storage to give you a url.

Comment: That's a great idea @martin66, does that imply that the url for the image in firebase storage is always the same?

Comment: Yes the url never changes unless you revoke or refresh the access token manually.